# ArcGIS online Feature layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online

I am trying do some analysis of two feature layers in ArcGIS online. Basically, I want to extract and show only the points that are within the boundaries of the second layer. Trying to perform "Select by location" type of analysis but in AGOL. Filtering through the definition query won't work since these are two different feature layers.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you have access to service credits and the analysis tab?

Comment: Yes, I do have both

Comment: @Tomas can you please mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Find Existing Locations analysis tool within the Analysis tab. Can input both features and define queries for a result layer

Comment: Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it. One more question if you don't mind. Will the resulting feature update as the data in the hosted feature services update ?

Comment: This analysis creates a results layer, I do not believe that layer automatically updates, but I think you can rerun the analysis with the same settings, overwriting